# scheme48: assertion-violation: undefined variable [global] array-dimensions user

Tags: installation, scheme, racket, scheme48

new to scheme48.  I'm wondering how to import the arrays module; looking to make 2-d arrays

I've tried importing the arrays functions as described [here](http://s48.org/0.57/manual/s48manual_41.html) both these ways:

```
,open Arrays
,open arrays
```

But when I try to run the sample code on that page (copied here:)

```
(define (transpose array)
  (let ((dimensions (array-dimensions array)))
    (make-shared-array array
                       (lambda (x y)
                         (list y x))
                       (cadr dimensions)
                       (car dimensions))))
(array->vector
  (transpose
    (array '(2 3) 'a 'b 'c 'd 'e 'f)))
```

it always gives me the same error:

```
assertion-violation: undefined variable [global]
                     array-dimensions
                     user
```

## How I installed scheme48:

I did everything specified on the official download page [here](http://www.s48.org/1.9.2/download.html) using `sudo su`, ie.

```
cd /tmp
wget http://www.s48.org/1.9.2/scheme48-1.9.2.tgz
sudo su
cd /usr/local/src
gunzip -c </tmp/scheme48-1.9.2.tgz | tar xf -
cd scheme48-1.9.2
./configure
make
make install
```

then

```
scheme48
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the final answer to this question, but here is a resource that might help people, especially those using scheme48:

http://s48.org/1.8/manual/manual-Z-H-5.html